# Kotlin: Unable to access value in an IntentService class

Tags: kotlin, intentservice

I'm pulling JSON from a URL and i'm using Gson to convert it to a usable PIN code i need to show to the user.

```
package example

import android.app.IntentService
import android.content.Intent
import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.net.URL

class SendOrderIntentService : IntentService("SendOrderIntentService") {
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {

    val orderNumber = (0..999999999999999).random()
    val goodsCode = "1001004"

    val orderURLPart1 = "URL"
    val orderURLPart2 = "URL"
    val orderURLPart3 = "URL"

    val orderURL = orderURLPart1 + orderNumber + orderURLPart2 + goodsCode + orderURLPart3

    val orderJson = URL(orderURL).readText()
    println("Order number $orderNumber")
    println(orderJson)

    val pinCode = Gson().fromJson(orderJson, OrderData::class.java)

    println(pinCode)
    }
}
```

Everything works so far, pinCode has the right data.

```
package example

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_meal_reserved.*
import example.R

class MealReservedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meal_reserved)
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar)

    textViewCode.text = SendOrderIntentService().pinCode
   }
}
```

But i can't get the textViewCode to display the pinCode, it just tells me its an

```
"Unresolved reference: pinCode"
```

I've been searching for an answer for hours so i think i'm missing something obvious and simple.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: pinCode is not visible outside SendOrderIntentService

Comment: 1) pinCode is a local variable that exists inside the `onHandleIntent` function. It cannot be accessed from outside of this.

2) You cannot instantiate a Service like this. You need to use some `startService()` method from the activity and send it an `Intent`.

Comment: @Can_of_awe 1) Is it possible to make it public in some way? 2) The service is being started just fine but it's done by another Activity